# Azure DevOps Classic Release - Artifact Filter always triggering release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps classic release pipeline
There are 2 artifacts (type build) with continuous deployment trigger enabled, and 2 stages
Each stage has an "after release" trigger with an artifact filter, to the respective build artifact.
The builds are for different repos.
However, both stage are being triggered when every build artifact is created, even when I manually create a release...

Expected behavior is:

1. Build A completes, only stage A is triggered
2. Build B completes, only stage B is triggered
3. When I manually create a release, I would like to choose which stage will be triggered. If this is not possible, the trigger both stages

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Classic Release - Artifact Filter always triggering release

For this issue ,I am afraid that it is currently not supported in azure devops. If you want different artifacts to trigger the deployment of different rows of stages respectively, it is better to create two pipelines, set the artifact in each pipeline to trigger the deployment on the required stages.

And you could check [this topic on developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/578950/re-run-a-single-stage-in-a-multi-stage-pipeline.html)

> Sorry I should have clarified a bit more. I don't think that triggers will solve all use cases, but having triggers on stages would at least allow you to have the following:
>
> 1. Stage A has trigger /src/appA
> 2. Stage B has trigger /src/appB
>
> If you commited (script, code, etc.) to /src/appB, it should use previous artifacts and only build appB and further if requested.

If you think that two artifacts only trigger a part of the pipeline is necessary, you could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: How can this be not supported if this is the exact definition of the feature? The tooltip for Artifact Filter says "Select artifact condition(s) to trigger a new deployment. A release will be deployed to this stage only if all artifact conditions match.". Note the word "only"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it only works for Git repos, selecting the branch. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-multiple-branches?view=azure-devops).